# Using iterative calculation to limit updates to an arrayformula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How can I limit the use of a arrayformula() so that it will only be applied the first time a value is filled in A:A.

For example, In B2 I have

```
ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A<>"",A2:A+1,""))
```

| number | formula applied |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **2*** |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |

In the above example, any time I change the number in A2:A the value in B2:B will change. Instead, I would like to restrict the application so that it only applies to any new AND nonblank values (Ie if a value is added below "6", such as 10 in A8 then the formula should be applied to apply the value). However, if I change a number 5 in A4, I would not like the value in column B to change.

I recall seeing some sort of solution that had to do with changing settings in the sheets but cannot remember the exact settings. I think it had to do with `File>settings>calculation>Iterative calculation>On` which adaptes "whether formulas with circular references are resolved by iterative calculation" but setting this to 1 doesnt work, perhaps because I would have to create a situation where a circular reference is created by the formula?

Perhaps there is another way to limit the number of times an arrayformula should be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A<>"",IF(B2:B="",A2:A+1,B2:B),""))
```

- `Enable iterative calculation` in sheets setting as in screenshot
- the `Column B` output value will not change if you just change an already existing value in `A` but if you completely clear the cell of existing value in `A` and enter fresh one post that, then `B` will change too!

[image]

---

[image]